# парсинг html(расписание игр) в tg бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

учусь парсить и поставил перед собой задачу создать тг бота, который по вызову будет отправлять расписание ближайших игр(брал инфу с сайта https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/)
написал вот такой код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# url = 'https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/'
# req = requests.get(url)
# src = req.text
# with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
#    file.write(src)
with open("index.html", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
     src = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
all_next_matches_dota = soup.find_all(class_="esport-match-future-list")
for item in all_next_matches_dota:
     print(item.text)
```

вроде бы все работает, он выдает мне имена команд, время, бк коэф, но происходит это все в неупорядоченном списке:

```
Ybb Gaming


                            6.85                        






                    07:00                    

                        13.04                    





Dandelion Esport Club


                            1.09                        

























Motivate.Trust Gaming


                            2.69                        






                    07:00                    

                        13.04                    





Lilgun


                            1.43
```

и так далее

подскажите, пожалуйста, как и где я могу отредактировать вывод(убрать лишние пробелы и переносы), возможно ли это вообще сделать и какую документацию мне надо изучить для этого?
заранее спасибо
так, прошло время и я понял, что стоит брать не все карточки, а парсить их по элементам(т.е сначала название, потом время и тд)
изменил немного код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/'
req = requests.get(url)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
all_next_matches_dota = soup.find_all(class_="cybersport-matches__matches-name")
c = 0
for item in all_next_matches_dota:
     print(item.text)
     c = c + 1
     if c == 20: #беру ближайшие 20 названий команд, т.е. ближайшие 10 матчей
          break
```

выдает:

```
Ybb Gaming
Dandelion Esport Club
Motivate.Trust Gaming
Lilgun
PSG.LGD
LBZS
Execration
Nigma Galaxy SEA
EHOME
Xtreme Gaming
Fnatic
Team SMG
Lilgun
No Sorry
Entity Gaming
Team Secret
Rune Eaters Esports
Hydra
cybercats
CHILLAX
```

теперь вопрос тот же, в чем и как мне отредактировать вывод, чтобы, допустим, 2 команды было в одной строке через дефис, а (в будущем) рядом стояло время?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если там данные в таблице, то и нужно парсить как таблицу - построчно, а в каждой строке вытаскивать поля столбцов, заполняя свои данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/'
req = requests.get(url)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
# "БУДУЩИЕ ИГРЫ"
all_next_matches_dota = soup.find('div', class_="esport-match-future-list").\
     find_all('div', class_="cybersport-matches__matches-match list-match-item")
for item in all_next_matches_dota:
     name = [x.text for x in item.find_all('p', class_="cybersport-matches__matches-name")]
     time_match = item.find('div', class_='time').text.split("\n")[1].strip()
     data = item.span.text.strip()
     coeff = [x.text.strip() for x in item.find_all('p', class_="cybersport-matches__matches-coeff")]

     print(f'''{' '*(19-len(name[0]))} {name[0]} {time_match} {name[1]}''')
     print(' '*16 + coeff[0] + ' ' + data + ' ' + coeff[1])

              Lilgun 15:00 No Sorry
                1.40 13.04 2.99
       Entity Gaming 16:00 Team Secret
                1.88 13.04 1.93
 Rune Eaters Esports 18:00 Hydra
                2.64 13.04 1.50
           cybercats 18:00 CHILLAX
                6.23 13.04 1.13
.....
```